# Override spring @ExceptionHandler methods

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

If I have a Spring Controller with two SEPARATE methods, one annotated by:

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
```

and another annotated by:

```
@ExceptionHandler(SubException.class)
```

And my controller throws `SubException.class`, does it get handled by both methods, or just `@ExceptionHandler(SubException.class)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One handler will be invoked on a best fit basis.

The exact implementation is in [`AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver.findBestExceptionHandlerMethod(Object,Exception)`](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver.java#L156)

Comment: Link is not active

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own annotation class which act as exception. And after that you need to provide your class annotation instead of Exception-handler.

Please let me know, if you have any query.

Comment: sorry, I phrased my question badly originally and have now edited it

Answer (score 0):

Handlers typically implement Spring’s Ordered interface so you can define the order that the handlers run in.

see [Exception Handling in Spring MVC](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)